# How to deploy loopback project on amazon-web-service s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, loopback

I am new to aws services. I want to deploy a loopback project on amazon ec2 such that all my modal api's can be accessible to my react app on cloud.

Comment: Are you talking about a LoopBack NodeJS app? You can't run NodeJS on S3. S3 is only for storing and serving static files. You probably need to look into running an EC2 server.

Comment: Yeah... thanks just got corrected my self.. anyway an you help???

Comment: Sorry but your question is way too broad at this point. Any way I can help with what?